# Why do Windows environment variable names use a special escape character?

Tags: windows, history, environment-variables

I am curious if there is any history behind why the `^` character is used to escape the special characters `<`, `>`, `|`, `&`, and `^` in environment variable names in Windows instead the `\` character that is typically used to escape special characters.

Please note that I realize there may be no reason for this, but I'd be interested to hear if there is a reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

'\' is the character typically used to escape special characters *on Unix systems* (or the language C, or any language inspired by C). Which is handy, because it's more or less the only use of that character in those systems / languages.

Windows, on the other hand, comes from a CP/M heritage, which uses '\' as path delimiter. (**Edit:** Not quite correct, see comment below.) Having to escape the path delimiter on each occurence would be a bit awkward, and I guess (!!) that's why they chose a different escape character.

Comment: CP/M didn't have directories, so the issue of what to use as the path separator didn't come up.  It used '/' for command-line options, and so did MS-DOS 1.0.  When MS-DOS 2.0 added support for a directory tree, backwards compatibility constraints prevented using '/' for the path delimiter, so it chose '\' instead.

Comment: ...and we've been suffering every since.

Comment: Especially if you happen to be not an US american, in which case you have to use `shift` and `altgr` to type `/` and `\\`, or you _simply can't_ when the keymap is not set properly (such as in some Linux rescue consoles). It's big fun when you're supposed to type some character that just doesn't exist on your keyboard.